# What are the differences between Access-Control-Allow-Origin and allow-timing-origin?

Tags: http

I was reading the official documents on the timing api but still got wonder, what are the differences between `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `allow-timing-origin`?

Answer (score 0):

1st header value controls which clients can call the resource (web service etc) and 2nd controls just the timing api specific. Broad vs specialized. If the first setting denies access, second will not be evaluated

Comment: I encountered such response that no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` was returned but only `allow-timing-origin`